# how to pass String to in sql to execute and generate output to outer query

Tags: oracle

I have a variable in oracle stored proc as

```
GDFCID_STRING2 VARCHAR2(1000);
GDFCID_STRING := ' select regexp_substr(''1005771621,1001035181'',''[^,]+'', 1, level)         from dual
connect by regexp_substr(''1005771621,1001035181'', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null ';
```

I want to use that variable to execute the same query in IN clause like this->
In stored proc I have one sql->

```
select * from xyz where gfcid in
(--here I want to execute the above query (GDFCID_STRING) 
and feed the output of query as input to IN clause--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the query in the `IN clause` itself. No need to dynamically execute it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   xyz 
WHERE  gfcid IN (SELECT Regexp_substr('1005771621,1001035181', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL 
                        ) 
                 FROM   dual 
                 CONNECT BY Regexp_substr('1005771621,1001035181', '[^,]+', 1, 
                            LEVEL) 
                            IS NOT 
                            NULL)
```

For example, let's see a test case using `EMP` table :

```
SQL> SELECT empno,
  2         ename,
  3         deptno
  4  FROM   emp
  5  WHERE  ename IN
  6         (
  7            SELECT Regexp_substr('SMITH,SCOTT','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  8            FROM   dual
  9            CONNECT BY Regexp_substr('SMITH,SCOTT', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
 10  /

     EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH              20
      7788 SCOTT              20

SQL>
```